# How can I translate Google Protocol Buffers to plain objects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am considering replacing a .NET WFC duplex endpoint with gRPC. Like most frameworks, WCF allows for the data to just be simple contract objects so what you use over the wire is what you can use in your processing code (if you are ok with that coupling). But with gRPC and GPB, it looks like I can't do that and I have 2 options. One is to translate my existing .NET objects on both ends of the communication, which will add extra labor/complexity. The other is to use the protocol buffer messages verbatim in business code, which couples business code to transport technology.

So my question is .. what is the best solution to use gRPC and avoid translation or direct use of buffers in business code?

Answer (score 0):

Both can be valid options: copy or use directly.

In larger/deeper systems it's good to translate to some "internal" objects that can have more fields and morph to the system without breaking clients. Those "internal" objects could even be protobuf messages. In this case, the duplication is a feature.

In smaller/shallow systems it's easy to directly use the protocol buffers without copying. You should realize that one day you *may* need to convert to some other version of the protos or make some sort of POJO or similar. But it's also possible that day never comes.

So the question isn't really, "Is it okay to use protocol buffers in business code," as that easily has few issues. But really the question is, "Is it worthwhile to allow the system internals to develop separately from its API?"